# js window.location not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a list of link(s) embeded in `<li>` tags e.g.

```
<ul>
<li><a href='/111'>Link1</a></li>
<li><a href='/555'>Link1</a></li>
<li><a href='/444'>Link1</a></li>
<li><a href='/222'>Link1</a></li>
<li><a href='/333'>Link1</a></li>
</ul>
```

i have written a javascript function which does the following takes the window.location.pathname of the currently loaded page and depending the param passed changes the location to point the next link or previous link, when i run the function from the developer console it works fine but when i fire the function in question via the normal route i.e. by click the next/previous links it konks off, i am unable to pinpoint what i am missing.

Function Code:-

```
window.navigate_to = function(event, direction) {
    var current_location, next_url, node, prev_url, url;
    if (event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event.stop) {
      event.stop();
    } else {
      "";
    }
    if (direction == null) {
      direction = 1;
    }
    current_location = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(current_location);
    node = document.querySelector("a[href*='" + current_location + "']");
    if (node != null) {
      next_url = node.parentNode.nextElementSibling != null ? node.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector("a[href]").getAttribute('href') : "";
      prev_url = node.parentNode.previousElementSibling != null ? node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("a[href]").getAttribute('href') : "";
      console.log(node);
      console.log(next_url, prev_url);
      url = direction === 1 ? next_url : prev_url;
      console.log(window);
      console.log(url);
      window.location = window.location.host + url;
      return true;
    }
};
```

TIA

Comment: how are you invoking `window.navigate_to` method?

Comment: as an onclick event handler